# plot_partial_dependence in sklearn not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I wrote down the code like suggested in their [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.plot_partial_dependence.html) but the following code does not show anything.

```
result=ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=2000,learning_rate=0.08,max_depth=4,min_samples_leaf=25,subsample=0.5,loss='huber')
result = result.fit(train_vars,train['d'])
features = ['a','b','c']
fig,axs = plot_partial_dependence(result, train_vars, features,feature_names=features, n_cols=2)
fig.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do
``fig = plt.figure();
fig.show()``
does that do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to do plt.show(), it seems the figure gets embedded to matplotlib's main grid.